# How to use projection_fields parameter in Bigquery Python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am trying to load the Cloud Firestore export in Google Cloud Storage into Bigquery using the Python API. I need to load only a select few fields for which I want to use --projection_fields parameter. However, I couldn't able to successfully use this parameter in my code. I'm referring this doc: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore

I am using google.cloud library.

Cannot find this field in the bigquery or firestore libraries.

Any tip on how to use this field using the Python API will be of great help.

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

creds_file_path = "xxxx.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = creds_file_path

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset('abcd')
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.DATASTORE_BACKUP
```

Comment: did you manage to get this to work in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the pyhon client library [changelog](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/CHANGELOG.md) it seems that does not support this option yet. However, you can use this workaround to include the projectionFields property, and for that matter, any property that is not supported by the client yet, but it is for the API.

```
my_list_of_properties = [] # The properties you want to include on the table    
job_config._set_sub_prop('projectionFields', my_list_of_properties)
```